# Visual C++ compiling error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, syntax

When compiling these two files I am getting numerous errors. Please help me out.

**stchart.cpp**

```
# include "peg.hpp" 
# include "stchart.hpp" 
# include "stchart_res.hpp" 

external PegResourceTable stchart_ResourceTable; 

PEGINT gChartData [] = (100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 
                        150, 100, 50, 100, 125, 100, 100, 100); 

PEGINT gBukData [] = (100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 125, 100, 
                      100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 150, 100, 50, 125, 100, 
                      100, 125, 150, 125, 100, 100, 100, 100); 


/*------------------------------------------------ --------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------ --------------------------*/
Strip Chart Window:: Window Strip Chart (PegRect const Rect &,
                                            const PEGUINT titleid): 
                                PegDecoratedWindow (Rect) 
( 
    PEGCOLOR tempColor1, tempColor2, tempColor3; 
    if (titleid) 
    ( 
        Add (new PegTitle (titleid)); 
    ) 

    PegRect Chart mClient = Rect; 
    ChartRect.Bottom = mClient.Height () / 2 to 2; 
    mpChart = new PegStripChart (Chart Rect, 130, -100, 700, 10, 100); 
    mpChart-> SetExStyle (mpChart-> GetExStyle () | CS_DRAWYGRID | 
                        CS_DRAWXGRID | CS_DRAWXTICS | CS_DRAWYLABELS | 
                        CS_SCROLLED | / / CS_DUALYTICS | CS_DRAWLINEFILL |  
                        CS_DRAWXLABELS | CS_DUALYTICS | CS_DRAWXLABELS | 
                        CS_DUALYLABELS); 
    mpChart-> SetExStyle (mpChart-> GetExStyle () & ~ CS_PAGED); 
    Add (mpChart); 
    tempColor1 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_CYAN); 
    tempColor2 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_BLUE); 
    tempColor3 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_MAGENTA); 
    mSin = mpChart-> AddLine (tempColor1, tempColor1, tempColor3); 

    tempColor1 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_LIGHTGREEN); 
    tempColor2 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_GREEN); 
    tempColor3 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_RED); 
    MID-mpChart => AddLine (tempColor1, tempColor1, tempColor3); 
    mpChart-> SetYLabelScale (200); 

    ChartRect.Top = ChartRect.Bottom + 4; 
    ChartRect.Bottom = mClient.Bottom; 
    mpChart2 = new PegStripChart (Chart Rect, 130, -200, 600, 10, 100); 
    mpChart2-> SetExStyle (mpChart2-> GetExStyle () | CS_DRAWAGED | 
                         CS_XAXISONZEROY | CS_DRAWXTICS | CS_DRAWXLABELS); 
                         / / CS_DRAWLINEFILL); 

    Add (mpChart2); 
    tempColor1 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_LIGHTBLUE); 
    tempColor2 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_BLUE); 
    tempColor3 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_CYAN); 
    mSin2 = mpChart2-> AddLine (tempColor1, tempColor1, tempColor3); 

    tempColor1 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_LIGHTGREEN); 
    tempColor2 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_GREEN); 
    tempColor3 = PegResourceManager:: GetColor (CID_GREEN); 
    mID2 = mpChart2-> AddLine (tempColor1, tempColor1, tempColor3); 

) 

/*------------------------------------------------ --------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------ --------------------------*/
PEGINT Strip Chart Window:: Message (const PegMessage & mesg) 
( 
    static PEGINT Index = 0, j = 0; 
    static PEGINT Angle = 0; 

    switch (Mesg.Type) 
    ( 
    PM_SHOW case: 
        PegWindow:: Message (mesg); 
        SetTimer (1, PEG_ONE_SECOND, 1); 
        break; 

    PM_HIDE case: 
        PegWindow:: Message (mesg); 
        Kill Timer (1); 
        break; 

    PM_TIMER case: 
        ( 
            if (+ + index> 17) 
            ( 
                Index = 0; 
            ) 

            mpChart-> AddData (MID, gChartData [Index]); 

            if (+ + j> 28) 
            ( 
                j = 0; 
            ) 
            mpChart2-> AddData (mID2, gBukData [j]); 

            if ((Angle + = 10)> 350) 
            ( 
                Angle = 0; 
            ) 

            PEGINT Sin, Cos; 
            PegLookupSinCos (Angle, & Sin, Cos &); 
            mpChart-> AddData (mSin, (PEGLONG) ((Sin * 125)>> 10) + 400); 
            mpChart2-> AddData (mSin2, (PEGLONG) ((125 * Cos)>> 10) + 400); 
        ) 

    default: 
        ( 
            return (PegWindow:: Message (mesg)); 
        ) 
    ) 

    return 0; 
) 

/*------------------------------------------------ --------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------ --------------------------*/
void PegAppInitialize (PegPresentationManager * pPresentation) 
( 
    PegRect Rect; 
    Rect.Set (10, 10, 630, 470); 

    PegResourceManager:: Install Resources From Table (&
                                                    stchart_ResourceTable); 
    Strip Chart Window * pWindow = new Strip Chart Window (Rect, SID_TITLE); 
    pPresentation-> Add (pWindow); 


)
```

**stchart.hpp:**

```
Strip Chart class Window: public PegDecoratedWindow 
( 
    public: 
        Strip Chart Window (PegRect const Rect &, const PEGUINT titleid); 
        Strip Chart virtual ~ Window () () 

        virtual PEGINT Message (const PegMessage & mesg); 

    public: 
PegStripChart * mpChart; 
PegStripChart * mpChart2; 

        PEGUBYTE mid; 
        PEGUBYTE mSin; 
        PEGUBYTE mID2; 
        PEGUBYTE mSin2; 
);
```

**ERRORS:**

```
     -------------------- Configuration: stchart - Win32 Debug -------------------- 
     Compiling ... 
     stchart.cpp 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.hpp (29): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.hpp (29): error C2501: 'PegStripChart': missing storage-class or type specifiers 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.hpp (29): error C2501: 'mpChart': missing storage-class or type specifiers 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.hpp (30): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.hpp (30): error C2501: 'PegStripChart': missing storage-class or type specifiers 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.hpp (30): error C2501: 'mpChart2': missing storage-class or type specifiers 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (45): error C2065: 'mpChart': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (45): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PegStripChart' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (46): error C2227: left of '-> SetExStyle' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (46): error C2227: left of '-> GetExStyle' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (46): error C2065: 'CS_DRAWYGRID': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (46): error C2065: 'CS_DRAWXGRID': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (47): error C2065: 'CS_DRAWXTICS': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (47): error C2065: 'CS_DRAWYLABELS': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (47): error C2065: 'CS_SCROLLED': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (49): error C2065: 'CS_DUALYTICS': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (49): error C2065: 'CS_DRAWXLABELS': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (50): error C2065: 'CS_DUALYLABELS': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (51): error C2227: left of '-> SetExStyle' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (51): error C2227: left of '-> GetExStyle' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (51): error C2065: 'CS_PAGED': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (56): error C2227: left of '-> AddLine' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (61): error C2227: left of '-> AddLine' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (62): error C2227: left of '-> SetYLabelScale' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (66): error C2065: 'mpChart2': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (66): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PegStripChart' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (67): error C2227: left of '-> SetExStyle' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (67): error C2227: left of '-> GetExStyle' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (67): error C2065: 'CS_DRAWAGED': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (68): error C2065: 'CS_XAXISONZEROY': undeclared identifier 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (75): error C2227: left of '-> AddLine' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (80): error C2227: left of '-> AddLine' must point to class / struct / union 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ')' 
     c: \ swellsoftware \ pegplus \ examples \ stchart \ plus \ stchart.cpp (82): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation 
     Error executing cl.exe. 

     ** stchart.obj - 102 error (s), 0 warning (s) **
```

Comment: consider reformatting your post, it's unreadable.

Comment: Care to reformat (indent your whole mess to the right a bit) and at least specify where are that "line 29", "line 82", etc.

Comment: what is  `ChartRect.Bottom = mClient.Height () / 2 to 2;` ? (to 2 ?)

Comment: Did your brackets get mangled? You're using '(' and ')' in a lot of places where you should have '{' and '}'?

Comment: There are so many syntaic errors due to the formatting. Nobody can guess whats the real error(s).

Comment: normally it makes no sense to show more than the first 3-5 errors as these normally are followed by errors when the compiler is trying to get back on track again.

Comment: also remove the spacing you seem to have everywhere "Kill Timer (1);" isn't a valid statement.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that PegStripChart is not declared in any of the files you've shown us and this seems tobe causing the first few errors at least.

Is it declared in peg.hpp?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention on your switch operator it should be:

```
switch (Mesg.Type) 
 ( 
  case PM_SHOW: 
     PegWindow:: Message (mesg); 
     SetTimer (1, PEG_ONE_SECOND, 1); 
     break; 

  case PM_HIDE: 
     PegWindow:: Message (mesg); 
     Kill Timer (1); 
     break; 
 .............................
 .............................

 And you wrote:

 switch (Mesg.Type) 
 ( 
  PM_SHOW case : 
     PegWindow:: Message (mesg); 
     SetTimer (1, PEG_ONE_SECOND, 1); 
     break; 

  PM_HIDE  case : 
     PegWindow:: Message (mesg); 
     Kill Timer (1); 
     break;
```

........................
.....................

Answer (score 0):

You are using ()'s where you should be using {}'s

e.g, your if-blocks, switch statements, method declarations, etc.